# Можно ли в python или в частности в pygame отсчитать время, не останавливая всю программу?

Tags: python, время, pygame

Я знаю о существовании методов sleep() у python и wait() у pygame. Но их минусом для меня сейчас является то, что они останавливают всю программу. Есть ли их аналоги, которые могут мне помочь?

Comment: pygame.time.set_timer

Comment: `https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer`

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите узнать ***время работы программы в секундах*** , то вам пригодится такая часть кода:

```
import time

startTime = time.time
while 1:
    # Что-то в цикле
programUseTime = time.time() - startTime
print(programUseTime)
```

А если вам нужно ***количество выполненных тактов*** (используется в играх), то при запуске игры сделайте `ticksGone = 0`, а в каждом цикле это число будет увеличиваться на 1. В зависимости от максимального fps в игре, время будет равно разному количеству тиков. Если вам надо будет найти значение в секундах (относительно игры) - тогда `timeGone = ticksGone / maxFPS` , где `maxFPS` - это максимальное количество кадров в секунду.